# How to make Axis 2 Proxy property aware of HTTPS for forward proxy server

Tags: apache-axis, apache-commons-httpclient

We are using Axis 2 framework to consume an external service for which we need to route the call thru a forward proxy server. I am using the below code to prove it out in lab but seems on actual proxy server (Which is https://.....) I don't seem to have a way to interact with Axis 2 (ServiceClient) which internally is using CommonsHttpTransportSender something with which it understands that hostname being passed is to be used with HTTPS scheme.

Is there an easier way to achieve this with CommonHttpTransportSender?

```
Options o = s._getServiceClient().getOptions();
HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties proxyProperties = new HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties();
proxyProperties.setProxyName(config.getForwardProxyServer());
proxyProperties.setProxyPort(config.getForwardProxyPort());
o.setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxyProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the RFC for Web proxy tunneling, I realize the requirement in itself is wrong, Forward proxy usually listens on HTTP protocol and simply facilitates a tunnel between client and server, if the proxy has to act as listening on HTTPS, then it would be more of a case for reverse proxy which wouldn't be applicable for HTTP proxy as question above originally stated!.

CommonsHttpTransportSender internally uses Commons HTTP Client 3.1 which uses HTTP Proxy as per RFC.